# How to select highest count in Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My Access database table ITEM has 2 columns: ITEMID and CATEGORY.

```
ITEMID  CATEGORY
I01 C01
I02 C02
I03 C01
I04 C02
I05 C03
```

I want to do a query that select the category of item having maximum number of items.
I wrote the query as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ITEM.CATEGORY
FROM ITEM
GROUP BY ITEM.CATEGORY
ORDER BY COUNT(ITEM.ITEMID) DESC;
```

The result comes as:

```
CATEGORY
C02
C01
```

Another version of the query (using nested approach) as follows:

```
SELECT ITEM.CATEGORY
FROM ITEM
GROUP BY ITEM.CATEGORY
HAVING COUNT(*)=
(SELECT MAX(TBL2.CNT2) 
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT2
FROM ITEM
GROUP BY ITEM.CATEGORY) AS TBL2);
```

The result comes as:

```
CATEGORY
C01
C02
```

Note that both the queries return same results, but with different ordering: first one returns C02 and then C01, while second one returns C01, C02

Please comment. Any better alternative?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there any better alternative to the query I wrote here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are fine.  Note that `TOP` in MS Access is equivalent to `TOP WITH TIES` in SQL Server.  That is, it returns rows with ties.

Note that result sets are not ordered (unless you include an `ORDER BY`), so the two result sets are the same.

If you want only one (arbitrary) category, then add another key to the `ORDER BY` to prevent ties:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ITEM.CATEGORY
FROM ITEM
GROUP BY ITEM.CATEGORY
ORDER BY COUNT(ITEM.ITEMID) DESC, ITEM.CATEGORY;
```

Comment: With ORDER BY COUNT(ITEM.ITEMID) DEC, ITEM.CATEGORY, the results come as only one entry: C01